# Why can't I go back to the Regalia sometimes?

Tags: final-fantasy-15

Usually when opening the world map, I have the option to return to the point where I left my car.

However, sometimes that option is grayed out and I can't figure out why.

When can I get back to the car instantly from the world map and when can't I?

Comment: I don't know the full list but I know if you are in the area of a hunt then you can't seem to fast travel back to car. I am not sure if there are any others though.

Comment: @Chris oh, you mean when I can't Save I also can't fast travel? This makes sense in a way.

Comment: Quite possibly. I'm not sure I've tried saving in a hunt area (and I should note I don't mean when fighting the target, just when in the big circle).

Comment: @Chris I did (I like to save a lot) and 100% sure that when in the yellow circle, we can't save. Will check if that's where we also can't get back to car or last rest point

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The short and simple answer is that you cannot Fast Travel whenever you are in a "dangerous" area or areas where the story won't allow it.

This includes places such as:

1. Hunt regions (when you're in a yellow area)
2. Dungeons
3. Story event areas (Such as Altissa)
4. During combat
5. > Anytime during chapters 9-14 (You are in the "end game" run and no longer have access to the Regalia, with the exception of the story event as the party enters Insomnia to fight Ardyn)

There may be others.

NOTE: These are not always the same areas you cannot save in, those are generally restricted to "Danger" zones only, unless you find a safe room.

Comment: Thanks! So you mean for example that when inside dungeons I will be able to save, but not get back to the car?

Comment: That's one example, yes.

Comment: Hmmm... last time I wanted to save in a dungeon it wouldn't let me. Are there only certainly places that allow that or something?

Comment: Sorry, i should have maybe been more specific. saving in a dungeon isnt allowed except at a campsite. The entire dungeon is considered a danger zone and doesnt allow saving nor fast travel, except back to the entrance.